# Creating a Graph object whose nodes are sets

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This question concerns graphs objects in Mathematica 8 when nodes are sets and not numbers or canonical symbols.

## The problem

What I try to do is simply the following. I have a set of sets. So consider the following:

```
S = {{1}, {2}, {1,2}, {2,3}} (* Set of vertices *)
E = {{{1}, {2}}, {{2}, {1,2}}, {{{1,2}, {2,3}}, {{2,3}, {1}}} (* Edges *)
```

Unfortunately when I do the following:

```
Graph[S, E]
```

Mathematica does not create the graph object and cannot understand my intention to create a graph having as nodes those sets.

## Question

What can i do to achieve this result? I thought about some substitution just to let understand Mathematica how to create connections, using inverse I can label vertices after creating the graph. But don`t know how to get this.

### Trials

I tried using replacement rules and operators, but the main difficulty is operating a substitution for an arbitrary length array. I`ll explain myself.

Consider to have a generic list of lists like `S`. I would have no problem in substituting it with a string like `{1,2,3} -> "123"` or `{2,3} -> "23"`.

The problem is that the replacing operator `/.` does not provide syntax for specifying a list in the way I want.

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You never want to use capital letters for your variable names, especially `E` is evil, since it is the euler number. Additionally, I think you have type in your braces for `E`.

When I understand this correct, then the only thing you have to do is, to make `DirectedEdge`s from your `E` list:

```
s = {{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}} (*Set of vertices*)
e = {{{1}, {2}}, {{2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {1}}} (*Edges*)
Graph[s, DirectedEdge @@@ e, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably a more readable version of @halirutan's approach:

```
a = {1}; b = {2}; c = {1, 2}; d = {2, 3}

Graph[{a -> b, b -> c, c -> d, d -> a}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
      ImagePadding -> 10]
```

Because it is a connected graph, you don't need to include the vertex list in `Graph`; the edge list suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Let me address this:

> Consider to have a generic list of lists like S. I would have no
>   problem in substituting it with a string like {1,2,3} -> "123" or
>   {2,3} -> "23".
>
> The problem is that the replacing operator /. does not provide syntax
>   for specifying a list in the way I want.

Starting with:

```
lists = {{{2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {1}}};
```

Here are several options:

```
lists /. x : {__Integer} :> StringJoin@Riffle[ToString /@ x, "-"]
```

> ```
> {{"2", "1-2"}, {"1-2", "2-3"}, {"1-2-3", "1"}}
> ```

```
lists /. x : {__Integer} :> ToString@x
```

> ```
> {{"{2}", "{1, 2}"}, {"{1, 2}", "{2, 3}"}, {"{1, 2, 3}", "{1}"}}
> ```

```
Map[StringJoin[ToString /@ #] &, lists, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{"2", "12"}, {"12", "23"}, {"123", "1"}}
> ```